# Is Sage Kashyapa mentioned in the Vedas?

Tags: kashyapa

Sage Kashyapa was a great Sage. Is he mentioned in any of the four vedas.

Answer (score 3):

Kaśyapa Mārῑca [son of Marῑci] (sixth of the famous saptarshi) is mentioned in a mantra in Rig Veda (9.114.2):

> ऋषे मन्त्रकृतां स्तोमैः **कश्यपो**द्वर्धयन् गिरः । सोमं नमस्य राजानं यो जज्ञे वीरुधां पतिरिन्द्रायेन्दो परिस्रव ॥

He is also the rishi attributed to the following hymns in Rig Veda:

1.99 (rather famous - and part of the popular collection called 'Durga Suktam')

> जातवेदसे सुनवाम सोममरातीयतो निदहाति वेदः । स नः पर्षदति दुर्गाणि विश्वा नावेव सिन्धुं दुरितात्यग्निः ॥

8.29

> बभ्रुरेको विषुणः सूनरो ...

9.64

> वृषा सोम द्युमाँ असि ...

9.67.4–6

> इन्दुर्हिन्वानो अर्षति ...

9.91–92

> असर्जि वक्वा रथ्ये यथाजौ ...

9.113–114

> शर्यणावति सोममिन्द्रः पिबतु ...

Comment: Can you give translation for other verses

Comment: @DarkKnight Translation for each mantra of all those hymns would take up a lot of space. I just provided the beginning of each hymn for reference.

Comment: So can you give a link to them because it is very hard to find a good translation of vedas.

Comment: Only the one I can find is ralff t Griffith

Comment: @DarkKnight Unfortunately, I don't have a good reference for a full good translation of Vedas. The only ones are by western translators like Griffith, which can be misinterpretation. I studied Sayanacharya's Sanskrit commentary, and I only use that for reference and I translate to English from that when needed.